# how to fill a Bootstrap popover through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I know that this question has been asked before,I have read the answer,implemented it,but I am facing one small problem.

In the PHP file I am trying to make an anchor tag and then display it in the popover,but instead making it clickable,the whole content(along with the anchor tag) is displayed.
Also,once the icon is clicked,it sticks around and doesn't go away even after clicking on it or anywhere else on the page.

Here is the code:

**HTML file:**

```
<li style="margin-left: 15px;">

    <a href="#" data-placement="bottom" title="notifications" data-poload="notification_list.php" id="id-wala">
    <img src="assets/ring.png" width="25" height="25" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="notifications">

   </a>

  </li>
```

**AJAX code**

```
$('*[data-poload]').click(function() {
            console.log('Hey');
        var e=$(this);
        e.off('click');
        e.unbind('click')
        $.get(e.data('poload'),function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            e.popover({content: d}).popover('show');
        });
    });
```

**PHP file**

```
    <?php
           #The code for connecting to the database removed for clarity.
           $sql1 = "SELECT PID from post where UID = '$a'";
           $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
           $end_result = '';
           while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
             $temp = $row1["PID"];
             $sql = "SELECT * from comment where status = 'unread' and PID = '$temp' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                      $end_result='<a href ="#" >'.'Notification from '.$row["UID"].'</a>';
                        echo $end_result;
                        echo '<br/>';
                    }
            }
        }
           $conn->close();
    ?>
```

The problem is that the  **echo $end_result** is printing `<a href ="#" >Notification from 89</a>` instead of **Notification from 89** and making it clickable.

Please provide some suggestions on how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because by default the `html` property on the popover is `false`. This means any HTML you attempt to place inside the popover content will be removed. To change this behaviour you need to set `html: true`.

You'll also need to use `trigger: 'manual'` and use the `toggle` option to hide/show the popover on successive clicks. Try this:

```
e.popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: d
}).popover('toggle');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8mgvosbm/)

[Bootstrap Popover documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options)

Comment: Thanks a lot!,it solved it,just one more thing.How do I disable it on clicking on it again?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - what are you trying to disable?

Comment: I mean if I click the image second time,how do I make the popover disappear?

Comment: Just one thing more please,my PHP file is being called only on the first click,how do I make it run on every click,I used ajax call before but it doesn't displays the data in the popover and destroys the css,how can I achieve this functionality by the method used above?

Comment: Delete the calls to `unbind()` and `off()`

Comment: But if I remove these calls,the popover doesn't go away on the second click

Comment: You also need `trigger: 'manual'`. Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8mgvosbm/